# How to set Dynamically react-native-material-menu in Flatlist

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'll try to set menu in flatlist component in dynamically, but the problem is that it just opening only last list item menu. how I will be an open sperate menu for each list item. my screen look like this.

```
<FlatList
    data= {this.state.DataList}
    extraData={ this.state }
    renderItem={({item}) =>
        <Card>
            <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Comment', {id:item.id})}>

                <Image source={{uri: item.image}} style={{height: 200, width: '100%', position:'absolute'}}/>
                <Menu ref={this.setMenuRef} button={<Text onPress={() => this.showMenu(item.id)}>Show menu</Text>}>
                    <MenuItem onPress={this.hideMenu}>Menu item 1</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem onPress={this.hideMenu}>Menu item 2</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem onPress={this.hideMenu} disabled>Menu item 3</MenuItem>
                    <MenuDivider />
                    <MenuItem onPress={this.hideMenu}>Menu item 4</MenuItem>
                </Menu>

            </TouchableOpacity>
        </Card>}
/>
```

and menu declaration is

```
import Menu, { MenuItem, MenuDivider } from 'react-native-material-menu';
_menu = null;

setMenuRef = ref => {
    this._menu = ref;
};

hideMenu = () => {
    this._menu.hide();
};

showMenu = (id) => {
    console.log(id);
    this._menu.show();
};
```

Comment: Looks like what? There is no image, nor example code to even begin attempting to offer help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this way

```
<Menu
    ref={ref => (this[`menu${index}`] = ref)}
    button={
       <Text>Show Menu</Text>
    }
>
    <MenuItem onPress={() => this[`menu${index}`].hide()}>
       Menu 1
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuDivider />
    <MenuItem onPress={() => this[`menu${index}`].hide()}>
       Menu 2
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```